ON SIT env It is not showing nonce value on style tag using Angular 16
I am using Angular 16. I have applied CSP policy by removing unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval and replaced with nonce-noncestring.
Now I am providing both CSP_NONCE in main.ts and ngCspNonce ="myNonceString" in index.html.
In localhost I can see that all style tags in DOM have nonce="myNonceString".
But on SIT env I can see that styles are getting applied correctly but nonce is not displaying.
Ideally as I have removed unsafe-inline, It should block styles from executing.
From main.ts CSP_NONCE is also getting set correctly. I can see the nonce value in getNonce() function. Then Why It is not displying that nonce on style tag.
Is it like angular has Internally considerd nonce value but not showing on style tag?
My Code:
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { CSP_NONCE } from '@angular/core';

function getNonce() {
  const metaTag = document.querySelector('meta[name="csp-nonce"]') as HTMLMetaElement;
  const cspNonce = metaTag.content;
  return cspNonce;
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [
    { provide: CSP_NONCE, useValue: getNonce() }
  ]
})
.catch(err => console.error(err));

In localhost It is showing it properly.

Could you caching issue? check the server, mainly index.html should not be cached!
